# JQuery validation plugin - error highlight problem

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form with two input textboxes, and I have included jQuery validation rules for both:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#respondForm').validate({ onclick: false,
      onkeyup: false,
      onfocusout: false,
      highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css({ backgroundColor: 'Red' });
      },
      errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div.error-container')),
      wrapper: 'li',
      rules: {
        'text': {
          required: true,
          minlength: 5,
          maxlength: 10
        },
        integer: {
          required: true,
          range: [0, 90]
        }
      },
      messages: {
        'text': {
          required: "xxx_Required",
          minlength: "XXX Should be greater than 5",
          maxlength: "XXX Cannot be greater than 10"
        },
        integer: {
          required: "is required",
          range:  "is out of range: [0,90]"
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
.
.
.
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" />    
<br />
<input type="text" id="integer" name="integer" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<br />
```

I have used:

```
function(element, errorClass) {
  $(element).css({ backgroundColor: 'Red' });
}
```

to highlight the error control. Now the problem is that in the following scenario, both the input textboxes remain highlighted (background color: red):

1. Input text with less than 5 characters in text box 1
2. Leave text box 2 blank
3. Hit submit
4. Both input text box background will be changed to red (which is correct)
5. Now enter a text which has 6 characters in text box 1 (valid input)
6. Leave text box 2 empty
7. Hit submit
8. The background color for both the textboxes remains red. Where as the expectation is that the background color of text box 1 should not be red

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer, you have to provide an `unhighlight` property as well.

*Adds the error class to both the invalid element and its label*

```
$(".selector").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).addClass(errorClass);
     $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                    .addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
     $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
     $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
                    .removeClass(errorClass);
  }
});
```

[More info](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)

Answer (score 2):

The function you used to highlight the error control sets the css property `backgroundColor` to `'red'` using the `jQuery.css()` function, which puts the rule in the `style` attribute on the element.  If you don't have another callback function that resets the background on the element to `inherit` using the `jQuery.css()` function, or otherwise overrides/removes the rule in the style tag, then the rule will stay in place and the form element will continue to have a red background.

What you should really do is set the background on the form element indirectly by applying a css class rule to it (Is the `errorClass` argument to your callback supposed to be a css classname to apply on error? I that case you should use that).  That way when the form submits you could easily reset the appearance of the form and revalidate:

```
$('#theForm .errorClassName').removeClass('errorClassName');
$('#theForm').validate();
```

Comment: Yes, this answer was quite close, but i could do it by providing the unhighlight property