# jquery validate: highlight a label shared between two elements

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have two elements that share a label.

[image: label shared by state and zip fields]

I need to add/remove a CSS class on it as the two elements are being validated. If one or both are invalid - label needs to turn red. If both are valid - label is marked as valid.

Can't figure out how to do it without entering an endless loop, where one element triggers the other's validation, which in turn triggers the first one's, etc. I can only think of using the highlight/unhighlight methods for now.

**EDIT:** Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalbaeb/gkTYG/7/) to play with.

```
$("#my-profile-form").validate({
    errorContainer: "#errorProfile",
    highlight: function(el, errorClass, validClass) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if($el.attr('name') == 'state'){
            $el.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $el.parents('fieldset').addClass('error');
        } else if ($el.attr('name') == 'zip') {
            $el.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $el.parents('fieldset').addClass(errorClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function(el, errorClass, validClass) {
        var $el = $(el);

        if($el.attr('name') == 'state'){
            $el.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else if($el.attr('name') == 'zip') {
            $el.removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $el.parents('fieldset').removeClass(errorClass);
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
        return true;
    },
    ignore: "", // needed to validate drop-downs in IE
    rules: {
        zip: {
            postalcode: true,
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        zip: {
            postalcode: "&nbsp;Please specify a valid zip code.",
            required: "&nbsp;The zip field is required."
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to write this into a jsFiddle, so we could experiment with the code?

Comment: hard to help without knowing if the `highlight/unhighlight` methods are working or not. Some live html in jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: @MrXenotype: everything is working, except what I described, which I don't even know how to start on. Just need an in-principle idea of how to implement this functionality. Even pseudocode would do just fine. :)

Comment: we can only guess what your markup is like. You can set this up in jsfiddle using CDN resources for plugin

Comment: I found this article which may provide some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707349/jquery-validation-plugin-error-highlight-problem

Comment: Even if you can't figure out how to make a jsFiddle, posting your HTML would be very helpful to anyone else who wanted to make a fiddle of this.

Comment: I just spent the last hour with two totally different approaches to this problem and both failed.  It seems that the common problem is that when a field is invalid/blank on blur, its "status" always reverts to `valid` when it regains focus, even if it's still blank.

Comment: @Sparky672 could you demonstrate it perhaps on my jsfiddle? curious to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up not using validator to solve the issue. I attach a 'change' handler to both elements and do all the work in there.

```
var v_profile = $("#my-profile-form").data('validator');
$("select.state, input.zip").on('change', { errorClass: v_profile.settings.errorClass, validClass: v_profile.settings.validClass }, function(ev){
    var validator = $(this).parents('form').data('validator');
    var res1 = validator.element( "select.state" );
    var res2 = validator.element( "input.zip" );
    if(res1 && res2){ 
        $(this).parents('fieldset').addClass(ev.data.validClass).removeClass(ev.data.errorClass); 
    } else { 
        $(this).parents('fieldset').addClass(ev.data.errorClass).removeClass(ev.data.validClass); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
...
if($el.attr('name') == 'state' || $el.attr('name') == 'zip'){
    $el.addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    $el.siblings('label:not([generated])').AddErrorClassIfNotAlreadyPresent();
}
...
```

Comment: sure that may work on highlight, but what about the case of removing the class?